# Is there an alternative to Json in Blazor WebAssembly API?

Tags: c#, json, blazor

One thing that I like about Blazor WebAssembly is the possibility to share a class between the client and the .Net Core server. Let's make this example where there are 3 prjs:

1. A Blazor WebAssembly one - the client
2. A ASP.Net Core one - the server where I host my API
3. A Class Prj where I define my classes

Both Blazor and ASP.Net prjs reference the Class Prj. Imagine the classic Blazor demo, we can say that WeatherForecast is defined in the Class prj, in the ASP.Net prj there's an API method that retrieves data from DB and fill the WeatherForecast array, serialize it to pass it to the Blazor client which deserialize it again into a WeatherForecast array.

I wonder if there is a more efficient way to transfer data between the api and the blazor app.

Serializing it to a json and then deserializing it back to a WeatherForecast array doesn't sound like the best option. Is there a way to transfer the data in another format, maybe a compressed binary that should be lighter and faster to transfer than a Json?

Comment: JSON is pretty standard, are you sure you will gain a lot by using another protocol? You can check out the new gRPC project type in .NET Core 3 though.

Comment: SignalR is now supported https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr-blazor-webassembly?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: JSON is text and not very verbose (far less so than XML for example)... should be pretty lightweight. Most JSON files are only a few Kb, not going to trouble most connections. Are you experiencing a real issue with something here, or is this just a speculative question? You have to use some kind of format to transfer data over the wire. JSON is pretty efficient for that - probably one of the reasons it's popular. But it's hard to see why you couldn't use some other format if you really wanted to try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @DavidG mentioned you might want to take a look at gRPC.

This video shows a good introduction to it in Blazor between client and server: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ess1SBBMmhg
Starting from 5:30.

gRPC for Blazor WebAssembly (client-side) is not yet in preview (a future feature as the video show). But will be after the May GA release of Blazor WebAssembly. So expected to be GA in .NET 5 and in preview after May.

With that being said, you can still make it work between client and server [in other ways](https://github.com/razfriman/BlazorGrpc)

gRPC requires HTTP/2

Comment: Thanks @DavidG, protobuf sounds very interesting, I still have to understand if using protobuf instead of json in rest is an option or it is better to buy the whole package (gRPC).